# How to name an element in a loop?

Tags: r

I am making a list of 76 components means, ranging from 0 to 0.75.
I would like to know how to name the component dynamically. 
For example, I'd like to name the component lis_0,lis_0.01,lis_0.02 and so on.
Also, instead of making a list with 76 components, how could I make each component an individual matrix?

thank you :)

I've tried the online sources.

```
x <- seq(0,0.75,0.01)
lis <-list()
for ( i in x) {lis<-matrix(rnorm(1000,mean = i,sd=1))}
```

I'd like to name the component lis_0,lis_0.01,lis_0.02 and so on.

Comment: What is `std`? You did not specify that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may have some issues in your code. For example, **std** is not defined and you are creating a *list* and then assigning a *matrix*.

Nevertheless, I think the core of your problem create a new object during each iteration and name it properly. This can be achieved using the **assign()** function.

Here is an example.

```
x <- seq(0,0.75,0.01)

for ( i in x) {
  lis <- matrix(rnorm(1000, mean = i, sd = sd(x)))
  name <- paste("lis",i, sep = "_")
  assign(name, lis)
}
```

I think you can start working from it.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter what `std` is, here is how you can specify the name. The key is to use the `names` function and use `paste0` to create the name.

Here I also introduced you the `lapply` function, which is a nice alternative to `for-loop`.

```
set.seed(1)

x <- seq(0,0.75,0.01)

lst <- lapply(x, function(x) matrix(rnorm(1000, mean = x, sd = 1)))

names(lst) <- paste0("lis_", x)
```